# Tailwind in React project - getting "Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'" error during setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, tailwind-css, npx

I'm following the documentation for setting up Tailwind in a React project over on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app. I've been following the steps, but when I get to the part where I'm supposed to run `npx tailwindcss init` in order to generate a `tailwind.config.js` file, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\16096\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\commands\build.js
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\16096\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\commands\index.js
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\16096\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\main.js
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\16096\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli.js
```

I've checked that I have `autoprefixer` in my `node_modules` folder and tried reinstalling it, but I get the same error. In my `package.json`, I have the following:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
...
```

as per the documentation. My `craco.config.js` file is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

again, as per the documentation. I've also tried reinstalling the `@craco/craco` package to no avail, so at this point I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try npm install autoprefixer?

Comment: @SinanYaman Yes, I've mentioned this in the question. I checked that it's in `node_modules` and tried running `npm i autoprefixer` again but I come back to the same error.

Comment: recently I got the same error but not in setup, it was a production error, I mistakenly imported a function from `autoprefixer` which I installed as a development module so it could not find what I imported when rendering the page

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest

npx tailwindcss init -p

npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

here: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/2831

Comment: This solution did not work for me in CI, as I am using ui.shadcn.com with tailwindcss

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same problem.

at first I faced “Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'” error during setup.

than I tried "yarn" instead of "npm".

rest of process will be remain same.

it works now.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is sometimes you install `tailwind` instead of `tailwindcss`

`pnpm add tailwindcss`

-- not --

`pnpm add tailwind`

Answer (score 0):

This is simple way for Creating The Tailwind Configuration File

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
npx tailwindcss init
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:-

`yarn add tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`

instead of,

`npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I updated **npm** and **nodejs** and error is gone. Maybe it is a compatibility error.

`npm update -g npm`

`{yourpackagemanager} upgrade nodejs -y`

npm updated from "**6.11.3**" to "**6.14.17**".

nodejs updated from "**v12.10.0**" to "**v18.9.1**".

Answer (score 0):

In my case while copying project I missed `postcss.config.js` file which was having below content

```
module.exports = {
 plugins: [require('autoprefixer')],
};
```

I added it in root directory of the project and its working fine, putting here in case someone is using postcss.

Answer (score 0):

In your Continuous Integration (CI) environment, the issue might be due to `autoprefixer`, `postcss`, and `tailwindcss` being listed under `devDependencies` in your `package.json` file. When your CI is in production mode, it doesn't install packages listed under `devDependencies`.

To resolve this, you can move these packages to `dependencies` in your `package.json` file. After making this change, run `npm i` to install the necessary packages. This adjustment resolved a similar issue in a project that used ui.shadcn.com with Tailwind CSS in a CI environment.