# WheneverIi run "npm start "in react i get Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

> Failed to compile
> ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
> Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'

Comment: Please [search your error](https://www.google.com/search?q=cannot+find+module+%27autoprefixer%27+site:stackoverflow.com) before asking

Comment: try running `npm install` first?

Comment: does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179304/tailwind-in-react-project-getting-cannot-find-module-autoprefixer-error-du/65179433#65179433

Comment: does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179304/tailwind-in-react-project-getting-cannot-find-module-autoprefixer-error-du/65179433#65179433

Answer (score 0):

```
cd node_modeuls/postcss-loader // you need check the correct library name from the error
npm i autoprefixe
cd ../../
npm start
```

Comment: i tried to install autoprefix but i got another new error

Comment: ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: Cannot find module 'cssdb'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method:

- Delete the `node_modules` folder
- use the `yarn` command. Or if you don't have Yarn installed, try to install it first with `npm install yarn` and run the command `yarn` to install the package you need.